# Can't migrate standalone MongoDB to Cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to convert a standalone MongoDB database into a cluster in order to migrate my database to MongoDB Atlas.

I've followed the following steps to try and convert it:

1. Stop my mongodb instance
2. Changed the configuration to the following content:

```
........................

#how the process runs

processManagement:   
     timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
   authorization: enabled

replication:  
  replSetName: "rs0"
```

3. Restarted mongodb with the following command: `sudo mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf --fork`
4. Logged into mongodb, to the admin database, with a user who has the following roles: `clusterMonitor, readAnyDatabase, userAdminAnyDatabase`
5. Executed the command `rs.initiate()`

And it gave me the following error:

```
{
        “ok” : 0,
        “errmsg” : “not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetInitiate: undefined, $db: \“admin\” }“,
        “code” : 13,
        “codeName” : “Unauthorized”
}
```

I have tried the previous steps in a dev server, and everything worked fine, bun in my production environment it didn't work, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Logged into mongodb, to the admin database, with a user who has the following roles: `clusterMonitor`, `readAnyDatabase`, `userAdminAnyDatabase`

...

> not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetInitiate: undefined, $db: \“admin\” }“

This error is expected since `clusterMonitor` is a read-only role.

To initialise or update replica set configurations when access control is enabled your user needs a cluster management role like [`clusterManager`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#clusterManager) or [`clusterAdmin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#clusterAdmin).

Comment: I will try this tonight and if it works, I'll buy you a beer.

Comment: it worked as expected, please send me your Paypal, I'm gonna buy you a beer.